# c# moving label with picture box when moved

Tags: c#, label, image

I have a football pitch with picture boxes in the shape of squares acting as players in my form. I would like it so when I select a picture box and assign someone to this position, the player's name would appear in a label below this.

As different formations can be used, I cannot have a static label, it has to move with the picture box. If possible it would also centre below the picture box, although this is not an immediate concern.

Currently, the assigned player's name is stored in a variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: You could just use the LocationChanged event to move the label.  Or change the label's Parent to the picturebox so it automatically moves as well.  Or just get rid of the label completely and draw the text in the Paint event.

Comment: I actually encourage @HansPassant's approach, if you're really into it to learn C#.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like a homework assignment.

I'd make the picture box + label into a user control.

Comment: It isn't actually a homework assignment, it is a small project I have given myself to learn c#! Ok thank you, I will look into this.